# CD Metadata: Finding and contributing

Tags: cd-ripping

I am transferring my CD collection to `.flac` files so I can enjoy it from my laptop. I have been using `banshee` and `sound-juicer` for the rip and conversion.

For some CDs, the metadata (Album name, Artist name and Track name) is missing for both applications.

I would like to:

- Make sure the data is not out there on the internet, and if it really isn't,
- Update it myself to a totally free DB so that any future user would benefit from my work.

Is there one central DB for CD metadata? Where shall I search and update the CD metadata in the most effective way?

Answer (score 1):

XBMC has a function for scraping websites for metadata. This data is found at places like CDDB, freedb, Discogs, etc.

More information can be found on wiki:
[XBMC wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XBMC#Scrapers_.28web_scraping_for_metadata.29)

If you want to look further into contributing to these listings, then you might want to look at contributing to freedb. More info can be found here: http://www.freedb.org/en/about_freedborg.2.html